# Facebook user_friends permission no longer returning friends who use the app after changing app name

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the Facebook SDK in my iPhone app, logging in the users with an FBLoginView placed in an Interface Builder XIB file and initialized in the view controller .m file's delegate method like so:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.loginView = [self.loginView initWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]];
    self.loginView.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}
```

I try to get the friend list after the user has logged in like this:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
}
```

I have two Facebook accounts using my app, so one should be able to retrieve the other in this request. It was working fine and retrieving the friend until today, when I tried to change the app name. Now, `friends` ends up being an empty array. I've tried deleting then reauthorizing the app on both accounts. I've ensured that both accounts are friends on Facebook. I'm stuck and out of options, just as I was about to submit my finished app to the App Store review!

My App ID on Facebook and my FaceBookAppID in my app-Info.plist are the same and never have changed. The only differences between before and now: I changed my app's bundle ID on developers.facebook.com, making it the same as my Bundle Identifier in my PLIST. My Display Name and my FacebookDisplayName in my PLIST were both changed and are now the same.

Comment: Did you ask both users for friends permission and both granted it?

Comment: @WizKid initWithReadPermissions should do that with @"user_friends" passed into the permissions array. I logged into Facebook through the app on both accounts. Strangely, the login page only said that the app was using the public profile, but I think it always did that. If there was an error, it shouldn't return an empty array for the friends NSArray but nil, right? I'll try setting a breakpoint and checking the NSError just in case ASAP (tomorrow).

Comment: @9000 `error` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was looking in the wrong place; the problem had nothing to do with the name change on Facebook. This code in my question, as I found out, was being called after the XIB had already called `init` on `loginView`, which was giving it only the public profile by default. Calling `initWithReadPermissions` afterward wasn't adding any more permissions; in fact, this call seemed to be ignored:

UPDATE: Actually, looking back on this, I think the issue was that I was calling `initWithReadPermissions` on my `FBLoginView` before it was even allocated. Newbie mistake on my part.

```
self.loginView = [self.loginView initWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]]; // loginView is an FBLoginView
```

But this works if I put it in `viewDidLoad` and remove the other code:

```
self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"user_friends"];
```

I must have only noticed this problem after the name change because I deleted the app from my accounts and re-added it, erasing the old user_friends permissions that had been granted before I was using a XIB for this view controller. Then I blamed the name change for it and searched fruitlessly on the Facebook dev site.

Comment: I tried your code, and still having the same problem. Can you please write me a more elaborate answer of how you fixed it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I didn't really do anything other than setting the `FBLoginView `'s read permissions in `viewDidLoad` instead of in `initWithNibName`. Looking back on this answer, I think the issue was that the `FBLoginView` wasn't even allocated when I was trying to initialize it... I was a novice a year ago.

Comment: Thanks. I initialized the FBLoginView in the init method, then set the read permissions in viewDidLoad as you described, and it works.